# Links on "Featured on Meta" and "Hot Meta Posts" headers

Tags: feature-request

I'd suggest adding links to the **Featured on Meta** and **Hot Meta Posts** headers in the box on the right:

[image]

The links would lead to the newest [featured](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/featured)/[hot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/?tab=hot) posts on Meta.

Would make Meta a bit closer.

Comment: Great idea!  Too bad it's been overlooked.